# Lightweight Container solution (from Vagrant/Virtualbox to ???)

Tags: virtualbox, docker, vagrant, lxd

Up to now we used Vagrant+Virtualbox to set up development environments.

The dev environment uses Ubuntu.

This was great, because you can start the dev environment from Linux, Mac, Windows.

But compared to LXD the virtualbox needs a lot of resources CPU/RAM and booting is slower.

Requirements:

- Support Linux, Mac, Windows as host OS.
- full OS (included systemd)
- persistent (changes should not get lost after a reboot).

Is there something like this?

**Update**

After talking to some people I got convinced that I don't need a full operating system. I will use docker-compose: Each service will be in one container.

Comment: LXD is _not_ virtualization. That’s why it’s faster. Unfortunately, that also means it cannot work on Windows or macOS. That’s a fundamental problem.

Comment: @DanielB if LXD is not virtualization, what is it? Sorry, for using the wrong term. AFAIK Docker works on Windows, so a lightweight ...(insert matching term)... does work on windows. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Docker on Windows runs in a VM, except when using Windows containers with process isolation. Containers is also the correct term. LXC (what’s inside LXD) is literally “Linux Containers”.

Answer (score 0):

I found this project: https://github.com/bdellegrazie/docker-ubuntu-systemd

It provides a Dockerfile with `systemd`.

The README explains the setup.